# ASINetworkQueue with order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to make queue with ten requests, and I want to load it in order.
How can I do it? Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

ASINetworkQueue runs all the requests in the order they were inserted into the queue. It is a first in, first out (FIFO) system.

If you want to ensure they all get run one after another rather than in parallel then you can set the concurrency to 1. The queue will start from the first request and run it one by one until it gets to the last request

```
ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];

// Here we add all our 10 requests, the order in which we add
// them determines the order they will execute

// Set the concurrency to 1 and fire off the queue
[networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[networkQueue go];
```

Comment: Please note, that ASIHTTPRequest is not actively developed anymore: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Comment: Just saw that, it is a shame. It still is a fantastic library which offers the most amount of flexibility when making requests. AFNetworking looks pretty cool as an alternative...

Answer (score 2):

Check [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) as ASIHTTPRequest is not maintained anymore. You can use it with [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html), which hast the property `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. If you set this to 1:

> Setting the maximum number of operations to 1 effectively creates a serial queue for processing operations.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
} failure:nil];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[queue addOperation:anotherOperation];
```